# Routing Error - No route matches [POST] for new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I'm getting an error with routes and I can't find where is the problem, I'm creating a simple CRUD and get this trouble with the create method.

#### Error

> No route matches [POST] "/usuarios/new"

#### Controller

```
def new
  @usuario = Usuarios.new
end 

def create
  @usuario = Usuarios.new(params[:usuario])

  if @usuario.save
    redirect_to usuario_path, :notice => "Cadastrado realizado com sucesso!"
  else
    render "new"
  end
end
```

#### new.html.erb

```
<h1>Add new user</h1>

<%= form_for (:usuario) do |f| %>

<p>
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
</p>
<p>
    <%= f.label :idade %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :idade %>
</p>
<p>
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
</p>

<p>
    <%= f.submit "send" %>
</p>

<% end %>
```

Comment: Just a couple of clarifications, mainly due to possibly not understanding the language. In the `new` method, it should probably read: `@usuario = Usuario.new`. In the `create` method, it should be `Usuario.new(params[:usuario])`. And like another mentioned, on the `redirect_to` you need to include `@usario`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Flexoid has pointed out, you probably haven't add the `new` method in the controller.

So, put this

```
def new
  @usuario = Usuario.new
end
```

**EDIT**

You have to pay more attention.

Take a look:

```
def new
  @usuario = Usuario.new # not Usuarios.new, that's wrong.
end  

def create
    @usuario = Usuario.new(params[:usuario]) # not usuarios, first letter should be capital

    if @usuario.save
        redirect_to usuarios_path, :notice => "Cadastrado realizado com sucesso!" # usuario_path requires an id parameter like `usuario_path(@usuario)` or you could redirect to the `index` with `usuarios_path` 
    else
        render "new"
    end
end
```

Comment: and you should consider start coding in english, not in portuguese, specially if you will need any kind of support from the community. Just a tip.

Comment: Usuarios is the name of my model not Usuario , and the first letter was my mistake , i already edit the question. Already change the model name to Usuario with out the "s" but still the same.

Comment: If you changed the model name to `Usuario` you need to change on your controller as well.

Comment: Also make sure you have named your controller right, `PostsController` and not `PostController`.

Comment: i wrote the code again in a new project in english this time and i didnt get the erro, but know im having a error with redirect_to,  im getting the following error , the url go to localhost:3000/user instead of localhost:3000/users 

 `def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  
  if @user.save
   redirect_to user_index_path , :notice => "Cadastrado realizado com sucesso!"
  else
   render "new"
  end
 end`

Comment: rake routes give me 

`user_index GET    /user(.:format)          user#index
           POST   /user(.:format)          user#create
  new_user GET    /user/new(.:format)      user#new
 edit_user GET    /user/:id/edit(.:format) user#edit
      user GET    /user/:id(.:format)      user#show
           PUT    /user/:id(.:format)      user#update
           DELETE /user/:id(.:format)      user#destroy`

Comment: What do you have in your `routes.rb` config file?

Comment: `TravelR::Application.routes.draw do

 resources :users

end`

Comment: At this point you should be able to redirect calling just `redirect_to users_path`

Comment: gr8 =D
i thought that had to be the same as the rake routes , but is the model path. thanks!

Comment: Indeed, your routes are displaying a weird path for the `index` method. But glad that's works!

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
<%= form_for (:usuario) do |f| %>
```

to

```
<%= form_for (@usuario) do |f| %>
```

Comment: then i get the following error in the new.html.erb page

"undefined method `usuarios_index_path' for #<#<Class:0x102cb15a8>:0x102b3bc28>"

Comment: Do you get the error after form submit? Try to replace `redirect_to usuario_path` to `redirect_to @usuario` in create method.

Comment: I get the error in the new form. 
keep with the same error changing `redirect_to usuario_path to redirect_to @usuario` in the create method

Comment: What is your model name: Usuario or Usuarios ? If Usuario, make sure you are not using plural form (@usuario = Usuario.new , not Usuarios.new , not usuarios.new)

Comment: By the Rails convention, it should be Usuario!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you forgot about configuring of the Rails Router.

Try to add this to your `config/routes.rb` file:

```
resources :usuarios
```

For the reference you can read rails guide [Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

Comment: Do you have `new` method in controller?

Comment: Yes i have -

 `def new
  @usuario = Usuarios.new
 end   `