# No route matches [POST] "/story/new" after submitting form

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

I've just started "Build Your Own Ruby on Rails" and I have had to use Google a lot, as the book seems to have a bunch of places where the code just doesn't work. This time, I couldn't find an answer. Okay, so here's the deal. I have a form that looks like this:

`new.html.erb`:

```
<%= form_for :story do |f| %>
<p>
    name:<br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
</p>

<p>
    link: <br />
    <%= f.text_field :link %>
</p>

<p>
    <%= submit_tag %>
</p>

<% end %>
```

It shows up fine when I go to `localhost:3000/story/new`. The thing is, when I try to type stuff into the form and press "submit," I get this error:

```
Routing Error

No route matches [POST] "/story/new"
```

My `routes.rb` looks like this:

```
FirstApp::Application.routes.draw do
    resources :story
```

`story_controller` looks like this:

```
  def new
    @story = Story.new(params[:story])
    if request.post?
      @story.save
    end
  end
```

The `story_controller` stuff for `new` is straight out of the book. I thought I might have had a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10863673/routing-error-no-route-matches-post-for-new), but no dice. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your controller code is wrong.  Rails follows CRUD and Restful practices.  A new action is always a get request and code similar to what you have as new should be in a create action which is a post.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you meant (note the at sign):

```
<%= form_for @story do |f| %>
```

That'll probably take care of your routing issue, but as John mentions, your controller action is a bit off, too.  The `new` action should only load a dummy model and display the new.html.erb page - the saving should take place in a separate action, called `create`.

Hope this helps!

**Edit:** Minimal controller code:

```
class StoriesController < ApplicationController
    def new
        #Make a dummy story so any default fields are filled correctly...
        @story = Story.new
    end

    def create
        @story = Story.new(params[:story])
        if(@story.save)
            #Saved successfully; go to the index (or wherever)...
            redirect_to :action => :index
        else
            #Validation failed; show the "new" form again...
            render :action => :new
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Eeep, sorry for the super late reply; I didn't see this till now. Hmm. When I change :story to @story, I get this:

undefined method `stories_path' for #<#<Class:0x3191508>:0x3196c08>

According to the book, it's :story because...that's the way Rails was designed. So, just because, basically, which I guess isn't the best answer.

Although about the create action, would that basically be @story = Story.new(params[:story])? And this is probably a super dumb question, but is a dummy model just basically a def new and then end, or there something else I should be adding?

Comment: @user1447477 - No worries.  But it's definitely supposed to be `@story`, not `:story` (you can check [the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html)).  If that's not working for you, I'd suspect it's because `@story` wasn't set up correctly.  I've added some example controller code, maybe that'll help clear things up?  Cheers!

Comment: Yeah, the book seems to be pretty out of date. Tweaking it with this, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

First off, Rails is relies on convention over configuration when using singular vs plural names. If you want to follow convention, you have to change the line in your `routes.rb` to `resources :stories`, which would generate following routes:

```
   stories GET    /stories(.:format)          stories#index
           POST   /stories(.:format)          stories#create
 new_story GET    /stories/new(.:format)      stories#new
edit_story GET    /stories/:id/edit(.:format) stories#edit
     story GET    /stories/:id(.:format)      stories#show
           PUT    /stories/:id(.:format)      stories#update
           DELETE /stories/:id(.:format)      stories#destroy
```

Note, that in this case you would have to rename your controller to `StoriesController`. However, your `routes.rb` has `resources :story`, which generates following routes:

```
story_index GET    /story(.:format)          story#index
            POST   /story(.:format)          story#create
  new_story GET    /story/new(.:format)      story#new
 edit_story GET    /story/:id/edit(.:format) story#edit
      story GET    /story/:id(.:format)      story#show
            PUT    /story/:id(.:format)      story#update
            DELETE /story/:id(.:format)      story#destroy
```

As you can see, indeed, there is no route for `POST /story/new`. I guess, the error that you are getting is triggered by following code in your controller:

```
if request.post?
  @story.save
end
```

It is quite wrong, because you trying to check for `POST` request inside the action that is routed to by `GET`. Just remove this code from your `new` action and add `create` action to your `StoryController` like this:

```
def create
  @story = params[:story]
  if @story.save
    redirect_to @story, notice: "Story created"
  else
    render action: "new"
  end
end
```

This should resolve your issue for now. But I strongly recommend using plural `stories` for your resources, since it will be back to haunt you again.

Comment: Guhh this is going to sound really, really dumb. I'm going with the story route for now since I'm not nearly confident enough to do a swap to stories. I added the code for create in my controller and made a new create.html.erb, but when I go to story/create, it says "unknown action: show." So I got rid of create.html.erb and went back to new.html.erb and tried entering something, but it gave me the old "No route matches story/new" bit when I pressed enter. Any idea what's going on? Thank you for any help; I'm so confused.

Answer (score 1):

This is the part that you (and me) have missed from the guide:

> There's one problem with this form though. If you inspect the HTML
> that is generated, by viewing the source of the page, you will see
> that the action attribute for the form is pointing at /articles/new.
> This is a problem because this route goes to the very page that you're
> on right at the moment, and that route should only be used to display
> the form for a new article.
>
> **The form needs to use a different URL in order to go somewhere else.**
> **This can be done quite simply with the :url option of form_for.**
> Typically in Rails, the action that is used for new form submissions
> like this is called "create", and so the form should be pointed to
> that action.
>
> **Edit the form_for line inside app/views/articles/new.html.erb to look like this:**

```
<%= form_for :story, url: stories_path do |f| %>
```